# How to set facebook permissions in activity login

Tags: android, facebook, android-fragments, facebook-android-sdk

I create an android application using Facebook SDK and it works fine with login fragment and i requested permissions like this :

```
  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_login_activity2, container, false);

    LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
    authButton.setFragment(this);
    authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_about_me","user_likes", "user_status","email","user_relationships" ));
```

Now i need to do the same thing but the facebook login need to be in a Activity so the previous code will not work becose `"authButton.setFragment(this);"` need a fragment that i dont have .

Also if i dont use the `"authButton.setFragment(this);"` i cant set the permissions because `"authButton.setReadPermissions"` will generate a `nullPointerException`

So what i am asking is how to pass my permissions to the facebook login in my activity

Comment: can you post the stack trace from the nullPointerException? If you're adding the LoginButton to an Activity, you shouldn't need to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Make your activity in the following way, no need to set `authButton.setFragment(this)`

package com.example.integration;

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.Request;
import com.facebook.Response;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;
import com.facebook.widget.LoginButton;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private LoginButton fbLoginBtn;

    private SharedPreferences mPrefs;

    private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Session session, final SessionState state, final Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        fbLoginBtn = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.fb_login_button);
        fbLoginBtn.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email"));

        mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null &&
                (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed()) ) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
        }

    }

    private void onSessionStateChange(final Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {

        if (state.isOpened()) {
            Editor edit = mPrefs.edit();
            edit.putString("access_token", session.getAccessToken());
            edit.putString("expires", session.getExpirationDate() + "");
            edit.commit();
            Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {

                    if (user != null) {
                        String firstName = user.getFirstName();
                        String lastName = user.getLastName();
                        String id = user.getId();
                        String email = (String) user.asMap().get("email");

                        Log.i("facebookid", id);
                        Log.i("firstName", firstName);
                        Log.i("lastName", lastName);
                        Log.i("AccessToken", session.getAccessToken());
                        Log.i("Email", email);

                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("name", firstName);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }

            });

        } 

        else if (state.isClosed()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please Login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(MainActivity.this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```